# Copy Custom Property and set it as a suffix of an object's name

Tags: python, scripting, properties

How to copy selected object's property and set it as a suffix of an object's name?
I have 3 objects in the scene, named a,b,c. Each one of them have a custom property named id with a corresponding value 10, 20, 30. What I want to achieve is to have that custom property pasted into their names as a suffix. Basically something like this:

```
a?id=10
b?id=20
c?id=30
```

[image: three objects - a, b, c with custom properties id=10, id=20, id=30]

Could you please suggest the simplest way? I was thinking about having some sort of a python script, that would allow me to do this for all of the selected objects in the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
import bpy
for ob in [*bpy.data.objects]:
    if not ob.select_get(): continue
    if "id" not in ob: continue
    suf = "?id=%s" % ob["id"]
    ob.name += suf
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But I noticed that some of the objects get named twice. Do you possibly know why it happens? I did a test, and it happens when I have a copied object with a name "a.001", then an object "a" gets named "a?id=10?id=10".

Comment: Mmmm, try this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, thank you, thank you!